# Why are parasitic capacitances the main factor for limiting high frequency performance of active devices such as transistors?

Tags: transistors, capacitor, capacitance, capacitive, parasitic-capacitance

According to the Wikipedia article, the reason for the limit of frequencies in which transistors operate is the parasitic capacitance. But I don't understand why this is so.

Wikipedia article:
[Parasitic capacitance](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Parasitic_capacitance#:%7E:text=Parasitic%20capacitance%20is%20a%20significant,of%20electronic%20components%20and%20circuits).

Comment: What other factors do you think might limit performance?

Comment: Are you asking "why" or "how"? "Why?" implies you want to know why it is not some other factor.

Comment: I wonder how parasitic capacitances limit the frequencies of transistors.

Comment: Do you know what an RC lowpass is? Resistances are everywhere. Without any capacitances (and inductances) the bandwidth would be unlimited. But **every** piece of wire and all PN junctions have capacitance. In combination with the resistances, that limits the bandwidth.

Comment: That wikipedia article discusses the bandwidth limitations of **amplifiers on a PCB**, it does NOT discuss the bandwidth limitations of the transistors themselves!

Comment: But the article says "This Miller capacitance (first noted in vacuum tubes by John Milton Miller, 1920) is the major factor limiting the high frequency performance of active devices like transistors"

Comment: @Amor Miller capacitance is something that appears in certain amplifier configurations.

Comment: @Amor You almost got where you needed to be, citing Miller's discovery. Why don't you read [Miller's paper](https://nvlpubs.nist.gov/nistpubs/ScientificPapers/nbsscientificpaper351vol15p367_A2b.pdf)? It's not overly difficult. One of the points he makes, early, is that the vacuum tube triode can "absorb power!" By this, he means that it doesn't just dissipate like a resistor but that it can retain some energy -- at least momentarily -- that can be returned. This is what capacitors and inductors do. It's a wonderful paper and I'm reading it for the first time. Thanks for that.

Comment: @Amor This is the same with many devices, generally. They include little bits here and there that can absorb or release energy that complicates them beyond a simple resistance behavior. In the case of an inverter (exaggerates the problem) with voltage gain (exaggerates the problem) and a capacitive absorb/release mechanism, you get the worst case. (The difference between the output and the input has the greatest rate of change.) The device's ability to absorb and release energy capacitively then works against this rate of change and fights it, slowing the output response. Read that paper!

Comment: @Amor, you may have noticed already. Your question cannot be answered by just one or two paragraphs, because there are several basic concepts of electronics which have to be explained to do so. Indeed it is like asking "why can't plants grow 100x faster when exposed to 100x daylight illuminance. The question is not precise enough to be answered without citing whole textbooks or lecture notes of a year's study. While I sympathize with your question, it is off-topic here, because it can't be answered here.

Answer (score 1):

Most of our circuits operate on voltage signals and voltage cannot change instantaneously across a capacitor coming from the equation that describes a capacitor \$I = C\frac{dv}{dt}\$. The \$\frac{dv}{dt}\$ is a derivative of voltage which means the voltage must be continuous which means it must be a finite, smooth, gradual slope. And any time you have two conductors separated by an insulator, you have capacitance. As you can imagine, that happens a lot.

Very similar to why does the mass of something limit how quickly it can vibrate. Because more mass = more inertia which means more energy to force it to change direction. Sure, you can make it faster by adding more energy to make it change faster, but if you keep adding energy, eventually something is going to give and damage will occur.